# How do I launch a process as a specific user at startup on OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, startup, launchd

I would like to run a script as a particular user on startup (not on login). I thought a launchd LaunchDaemon would do it, but 'man launchd' says:

"If you wish your service to run as a certain user, in that user's environment, making it a launchd agent is the ONLY supported means of accomplishing this on Mac OS X. In other words, it is not sufficient to perform a setuid(2) to become a user in the truest sense on Mac OS X."

They aren't kidding--when I try to run my script as a LaunchDaemon it doesn't work. In particular I'm trying to automate some keychain operations using the 'security' command, and it won't let me change the default keychain when I run the script through LaunchDaemon, though  the script works fine when run using sudo from a shell.

A LaunchAgent won't work, because the goal is for the proces to run without a user logging in and LaunchAgents only run when someone logs in. I looked at cron and the @reboot directive and that looks promising, but I read that cron is deprecated on OSX.

Answer (score 15):

I had similar problems trying to make a long running process use a default keychain. Essentially LaunchAgent doesn't seem to run in a full login environment for doing the security commands so changing the default keychain doesn't work and comes back with a permissions error on the `/Library/Preferences/` directory.

The secret sauce is to add:

```
<key>SessionCreate</key>
<true/>
```

to your plist. This is a undocumented feature which will force a proper environment and will enable you to set the default keychain. Credit to [joensson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237974/joensson) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827874/missing-certificates-and-keys-in-the-keychain-while-using-jenkins-hudson-as-cont) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If I edit my org.apache.httpd.plist to include this, it won't take affect until the system is restarted correct? I can't simply restart apache myself to do this?

Comment: This was the piece that I was missing to have the needed Keychain be available **BUT ALSO** had to do a **reboot** because a `launchctl unload` and then `launchctl load` was not sufficient. A full reboot was needed.

Answer (score 6):

Save as a global daemon (`/Library/LaunchDaemons`) and specify the user with key `UserName`:

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>Put username here</string>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as of today. Thank you

Comment: I did not worked for me. I am trying to run GitHub actions agent and it tells it is root and cannot run it. I set Macstadium user to my user and his default group.

Answer (score 1):

There are [a number of other places](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1226256) where you can hide startup items in OS X (most of which are thoroughly unsupported). I'd try `/etc/rc.local`; I seem to recall that working in Panther, so there's a possibility it might still work today.